# JqGrid: Trying to add a + button to the right of a "add" form field (using elmsuffix)

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jqgrid, scope

I can get the icon to show up, and it fires a simple alert if I place the javascript line in the href but I cannot attach a dialog object to the link id.

I am using "elmsuffix" to get the html there:

This works:

```
{name:'name',index:'name',width:100,  editable: true,  formoptions:{elmsuffix: "<a id="companysearch" href="javascript:alert('yay it worked!');" ><span id="companysearchicon" class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus" style="position:absolute; top:2px; right:25px; "></span></a>"}},
```

This does not:

```
$("#companysearch").click(function(){ alert('yay it worked!'); });

{name:'name',index:'name',width:100,  editable: true,  formoptions:{elmsuffix: "<a id="companysearch" href="javascript:void(0)" ><span id="companysearchicon" class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus" style="position:absolute; top:2px; right:25px; "></span></a>"}},
```

Its almost like the scopes are preventing the objects to work with each other (or am I just plain, approaching it wrongly)

Thanks

Andrew Finegan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I suppose you use `elmsuffix: '<a id="companysearch" ...'` and not `elmsuffix: "<a id="companysearch" ..."` to have correct syntax without escaping every `"` characters.

The problem from your question is **when** you use `$("#companysearch").click(...)`. At the moment the element with id="companysearch" must already exist in DOM of the page. So you should either use in inside of `beforeShowForm` event handler:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{},
    { // edit options
      beforeShowForm: function(form) {
          $("#companysearch").click(function(){
              alert('yay it worked!');
          });
      }
    });
```

or use [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method:

```
$("#companysearch").live('click', function() {
    alert('yay it worked (live)!');
});
```

In [the small example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/elmsuffix.htm) you can see live both the ways working.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply and help! Exactly, what I was looking for! (and yes I fixed my syntax also)