# jqGrid edit using formedit disable fields based on value of another field

Tags: jqgrid

When the user clicks on Edit in jqGrid, the form which opens has a few list boxes and text boxes. Depending on the value in a List box a couple of text boxes have to be disabled or set to read only when the form loads.

I got the piece working for the onChange event on the listbox to toggle the textboxes to disabled/enabled, but I am struggling to do it on the form load. I tried using the aftershowform, which already has a event handler, so I created another event say for example aftershowform2 and attached this event and the eventhandler fires. But the problem is the listboxes are dynamically loaded using an Ajax call (dataurl of editoptions) and aftershowform fires before these listboxes are populated with the options. Is there any different event which fires after the listboxes are loaded? The whole application is framework driven, and it is hard to paste the code.

Answer (score 1):

I see many ways which you can go to implement your requirements.

The first and the best one in my opinion would be the usage of `dataEvents` of the [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) with the `type:'change'` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192768/on-key-down-restrict-the-user-to-enter-some-special-characters/4198475#4198475) answer as an example). The corresponding code can be

```
editoptions: { dataUrl:...,
               dataEvents: [
                   {
                       type: 'change',
                       fn: function(e) {
                            var v=$(e.target).val();
                            alert(v); // do something with selected item value
                       }
                   }
               ]
             }
```

The binding to the functions defined by `dataEvents` will be after the successful return of the `select` contain from the server.

Another way would be modify your current implementation so that you replace [jQuery.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (see a code template [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961986/jqgrid-trying-to-add-a-button-to-the-right-of-a-add-form-field-using-elmsuf/3962545#3962545)).

Comment: I tried the change event, but the event does not fire when the form loads. As I said before, the change event fires when changing the option in the list box though.

Comment: @anamar: If it works not in your code, you should append your question with the full code. If I could reproduce your problem I could try to help you.