# jqgrid delete row only on screen and save the deleted row

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid with inline editing , when the user gets to the last cell inside a row , when he clickes on "tab" key he will be editing the next row - and if it does not exist a new row will be created.

I want to add a delete row function for the user , but still to have that row data inorder to send it later to the server as a deleted row.

I tried hiding the row , but then when the user "tabs" to the next row - it goes to the hided row - and i want it to go only to the not hided rows.

Is there a way to mark a row as deleted? and then when I generate the xml from the grid rows it will be a part of those rows? or is there a way to delete the row and save it's cells values , and be able to navigate throgh the grids line without going throgh the deleted line?

Any help will be appritiated!

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix problem with editing of hidden row you can try to add class "not-editable-row" to the row which you hide.

```
$("#"+rowid).addClass("not-editable-row").hide();
```

If it will not help you will have to overwrite the default "TAB" behavior of jqGrid (see [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628949/jqgrid-excel-like-enter-and-tab-key-navigation-in-cell-editing) for implementation details)

Probably more easer way would be to use [delRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) which delete a row from the grid without sending any information to the server. If you want to have your custom implementation of the "Delete" button in the navigator (see the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024075/jqgrid-navigation-based-on-the-selected-row/3024278#3024278)). Inside of your `onClickButton` event handler you can save the contain of rows, which will be deleted, to some JavaScript array/object and then delete the row with respect of `delRowData`. So you can trace all delete operation, save deleted rows and send later all needed informations to the server.